# Im getting an error about Datetime when Im just trying get the value of a cell from a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

In my `.aspx` design my gridview has a `apply` buttonfield. If the apply button is clicked, I want to get the value of the `cell[0]` from the row where the apply button is clicked. After I get that value I want to update the `exav_id` column in my database.

[image: This is the photo of the error I'm having]]

```
protected void gvExAv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "APPLY")
    {
        LoginInfo login = (LoginInfo)Session["login"];
        ApplyDAO applyDAO = new ApplyDAO(login.UserName, login.Password);
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvExAv.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text); 


        if (e.CommandName == "APPLY")
        {
            try
            {
                applyDAO.apply(id);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This my code on `appplyDAO.apply(id)`:

```
public void apply(int id)
{
     OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(String.Format("Data Source=Neptune; User Id={0}; Password={1}", UserName, Password));
     OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("UPDATE apply SET exav_id = :id", conn);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":id", id);

    conn.Open();
     try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
  
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your columns are loaded correctly in the Gridview and in the proper sequence? It seems Cells[0] is pointing to a datetime column instead of an ID column.

Comment: From your error, it looks like the value inside of gvExAv.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text is of DateTime object and not a string.  You're receiving that error because you're taking a DatTime object as a string, and trying to parse the string as an int.  What is the actual value of that cell?

Comment: Post your markup as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the value is in string but you are expecting it as integer value. Also there is a conversion problem.

Try this:

```
protected void gvExAv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gridRow = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer; // add this
    if (e.CommandName == "APPLY")
    {
        LoginInfo login = (LoginInfo)Session["login"];
        ApplyDAO applyDAO = new ApplyDAO(login.UserName, login.Password);
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int id = gridRow.Cells[0].Text;  // this one



        if (e.CommandName == "APPLY")
        {
            try
            {
                applyDAO.apply(id);
            }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

}